# What is “Prototype” in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain to me with simple words the meaning of "PROTOTYPE" in JavaScript?
I have seen one link but I am not clear about Prototype till now [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work), Please let me know about this.

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

Comment: Or watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMfcsYzj-9M&list=LLl2uvgeOh0_Iq7LMbaRVNww&index=254

Comment: read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming